# Increase text size on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, text-size

So here is my problem:
**On hover**, I want the **size of the font to increase**, but I want the **black container to stay identic** as before.

As you might understand with the example, the black container is also increasing.

This issue [How to increase only font-size of the text inside the text box on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014843/how-to-increase-only-font-size-of-the-text-inside-the-text-box-on-hover) is related but I don't want to use something like that (the size should be different according to the length of the text):

```
    position: absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
```

```css
.myclass {
    background: black;
    padding: .2rem .6rem .3rem;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.myclass:hover {
    font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Short</span></a>
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Example mid</span></a>
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Very long example</span></a>
```

Comment: What about this solution?https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

Comment: Isn't this similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687035/css-bolding-some-text-without-changing-its-containers-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `transform: scale()` instead of font-size. You'll need to move the some styling to the anchor element...

```css
a {
  background: black;
  padding: .2rem .6rem .3rem;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.myclass {
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover .myclass {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Short</span></a>
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Example mid</span></a>
<a href="example.com"><span class="myclass">Very long example</span></a>
```